# How to estimate the conditional probability of node reachability on a random graph?

Tags: probability, random-graphs, network

Let $G=(V,E)$ be an undirected random graph such that

- $V$ is the node set, $E$ is the edge set.
- Each edge $uv \in E$ is associated with a probability $p_{uv}$, i.e., $uv$ is kept with probability $p_{uv}$, otherwise removed.

Let $a-b$ denote the event that $b$ is rechable from node $a$. If so, as $G$ is undirected, $a$ is also reachable from node $a$.

My question is

> given three nodes $a,b,k$, what is the probability of $a-k$ under the condition $a-b$, i.e., can we estimate the value of $P(a-k|a-b)$?

I am wondering if the value can be estimated, because no more information is known about the random graph. If the value can be represented by $P(a-k)$, $P(a-b)$ or something else?

***EDIT***: **From the first answer, we've known $P(a-k|a-b)\geq P(a-k)$ and $P(a-k|a-b)\geq P(b-k)$. Can we have $f,g$ which are functions of $P(a-k)$ and $P(b-k)$ such that $g(P(a-k),P(b-k)) \geq P(a-k|a-b) \geq f(P(a-k),P(b-k))$?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I can say: $P(a-k|a-b) \geq P(b-k)$ since you can reach $k$ from $a$ through $b$ but you are not limited to it.

Comment: Since $G$ is undirected, I think $P(a-k|a-b)=P(b-k|a-b)$. From your answer, it has $P(b-k|a-b)\geq P(b-k)$. I can not figure it out.

Comment: You can reach $b$ from $k$ with some probability. But if you have additional $a-b$ connection, then it may only help.

Comment: Then, it also has $P(a-k|a-b)\geq P(a-k)$? Since in undirected graph it is symmetric?

Comment: Yes. it is true.

Comment: I am wondering if $P(a-k|a-b)$ has an upper bound. For example, if $a$ and $b$ are far away enough, maybe it is bounded by $P(a-k)+P(b-k)$? If $a$ and $b$ are near enough, for example, the extreme case $a=b$, then $P(a-k|a-b)=P(a-k|a-a)=P(a-k)$.

Comment: I don't think you can say that $P(a−k|a−b) \leq P(a−k)+P(b−k) $. You can say that $P(a-b) \geq P(a-k) \cdot P(b-k)$